# Referencing a bean with dependencies using Spring Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

In the following Spring Java Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("my.package")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public BasicBean basicBean1() {
        return new BasicBean("1");
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicBean basicBean2() {
        return new BasicBean("2");
    }

    @Bean
    public ComplexBean complexBeanByParameters(List<BasicBean> basicBeans) {
        return new ComplexBean(basicBeans);
    }

    @Bean
    public ComplexBean complexBeanByReferences() {
        return new ComplexBean(Arrays.asList(basicBean1(), basicBean2()));
    }
}
```

I can create two `ComplexBean`s using either parameter injection, which is elegant, but has shortcomings if a have a few other beans of `BasicBean` type and only want a few (the parameters can of course be of type `BasicBean` and enumerate by name the beans I'm interested of, but it could turn out to be a very long list, at least for arguments sake). In case I wish to reference the beans directly I might use the `complexBeanByReferences` style, which could be useful in case of ordering or some other consideration.

But say I want to use the `complexBeanByReference` style to reference the bean `complexBeanByParameters`, that is something along the line of:

```
@Bean
public ComplexBeanRegistry complexBeanRegistry() {
    return new ComplexBeanRegistry(
        Arrays.asList(
            complexBeanByParameters(), // but this will not work!
            complexBeanByReferences()
        )
    );
}
```

How would I reference `complexBeanByParameters`, without having to specify a list of dependencies to `complexBeanRegistry`? Which, the latter in all honesty should be completely oblivious of.

There is the option to just use

```
public ComplexBeanRegistry complexBeanRegistry(List<ComplexBeans> complexBeans) {...}
```

of course, but this might not be an option in certain cases, specifically when using the `CacheConfigurer` from `spring-context`. In this case the Java Config is intended to

1. create the beans
2. by implementing `CacheConfigurer`, override the default instances of the `CacheManager` and `KeyGenerator` beans.

The requirement to implement `CacheConfigurer` means I can't change the signature to use parameter injection.

So the question is, is there a way to reference `complexBeanByParameters` using the "direct" reference style?

Comment: My current solution is to split my configuration in separate files, and by autowiring the bean from one config, injecting it into the `CacheConfigurer` bean declaration -- the analogue would be to have `complexBeanRegistry` declared in a separate config and autowire the `complexBeanByParameters` bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could reference it with separation by Qualifier:

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("complexBeanParam")
    public ComplexBean complexBeanByParameters(List<BasicBean> basicBeans) {
        return new ComplexBean(basicBeans);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("complexBeanRef")
    public ComplexBean complexBeanByReferences() {
        return new ComplexBean(Arrays.asList(basicBean1(), basicBean2()));
    }
```

and for example autowire:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("complexBeanParam")
    private ComplexBean beanParam;
```

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the closest thing to what I want to do.